# How can I use multiple columns for DISTINCT?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm making a messaging system. Messages are two different kind.

- The first messages have a `title` and `NULL` for `related` column.
- The second messages are related to one of the first messages which don't have `title` and they have the of parent message for `related` column.

Here is my table structure:

```
// messages
+----+----------+------------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+---------+
| id |  title   |     content      | sender_id | receiver_id |  date_time  | related |
+----+----------+------------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+---------+
| 1  | titel1   | whatever1        | 1         | 3           | 1521097240  | NULL    |
| 2  |          | whatever2        | 3         | 1           | 1521097241  | 1       |
| 3  |          | whatever3        | 1         | 3           | 1521097242  | 1       |
| 4  | title2   | whatever4        | 1         | 4           | 1521097243  | NULL    |
| 5  | title3   | whatever5        | 1         | 5           | 1521097244  | NULL    |
| 6  |          | whatever6        | 5         | 1           | 1521097245  | 5       |
| 7  |          | whatever7        | 4         | 1           | 1521097246  | 4       |
| 8  | title4   | whatever8        | 1         | 4           | 1521097246  | NULL    |
+----+----------+------------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+---------+
/*
  related column: it is NULL for the first message and the id of the parent for othesrs.
```

Now I need to count the number of messages an user sent in a day to different users and different new messages.

So the expected result is  `4` for `sender_id = 1`. Here is my current query which returns `3`:

```
SELECT count(distinct receiver_id) as sent_messages_num
FROM users
WHERE sender_id = 1  
AND date_time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

My current query doesn't care about "new messages". It groups messages only per different users. How can I also add the concept of "new messages should be count too even if they are sent to the same user" ?

Comment: Why do you even use `distinct`? What you want is the same query without it (and the title of your question doesn't match your problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following query

```
SELECT sum(sent_messages_num)
FROM
(
    SELECT count(distinct receiver_id) as sent_messages_num
    FROM users
    WHERE sender_id = 1  
    AND date_time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
    GROUP BY CASE WHEN related IS NULL THEN id ELSE related END
) t
```

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=9cc5c95ff24045ed8a947d4a82556b0a)

Comment: eem, I will check it out, thank you. Just it's a bit vague for me. What's the reason of `SELECT sum(sent_messages_num)  FROM`? `sent_messages_num` is a number and does `sum(sent_messages_num)` make any sense?

Comment: Noted that I guess you should define a name for your subquery. Like `FROM ( ... ) x`

Comment: As a side note, how could you understand my question? I myself cannot understand if when I read it now :P

Comment: @MartinAJ I'm used to reading between the lines on stackoverflow :)  I'm glad it helped